# Specific Python reverse function questions

Tags: python

```py
def flip_keys(to_flip):  
    """To reverse items in a mixed list

    Args:
        to_flip(list): a list mixed with tuple and other values.

    Returns:
        list: to return values in the list, reversed.

    Examples:

        >>> flip_keys([(1, 2, 3), 'abc'])
        '[(3, 2, 1), 'cba']
    """
    counter = 0
    for value in to_flip:
        to_flip[counter] = value[::-1]
        counter += 1
    return to_flip
```

This is a python function, which is to flip each element entered, backward. I have learned indexing, but to_flip[counter] is like nothing I seen. What purpose does to_flip[counter] serve, in flipping each element? Does it have a name for this? And doesn't counter serve to add each number given, and to come out with a sum? Why is it needed here? And are there any other ways of doing reverse like this, for a beginner. Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: `to_flip[counter]`  accesses an item of the list `to_flip` at position `counter`.

Comment: What is `flip_keys([(1, 2, 3), 'abc', 1, 3])` expected to do?

Comment: And do you expect to get input like `flip_keys([(1, 2, 3), 'abc', [1, [[2]]]])`?

Comment: @ Tigerhawk, I understand it better now, you get an error from flip_keys([(1, 2, 3), 'abc', 1, 3]), for only elements in groupings are reversed. Maybe that's why you use the counter as the position in this case. Thank you.

Comment: @ siwica, I didn't know you could use anything else other than numeric values to index. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `to_flip` line is flipping whatever is in that element. For example if you ran it on just one list:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
flipped_list = my_list[::-1]
```

`flipped_list` would now be `[5,4,3,2,1]`. The `[::-1]` is a neat little shorthand for flipping any list.

For your code, `counter` is keeping track of what element you are in in `to_flip`. You could also keep track by using `enumerate`, which keeps count of what element you are at, on the list too:

```
for i, value in enumerate(to_flip):
    to_flip[i] = value[::-1]
```